# Getting Bootstrap grid system columns to remain fixed width on browser resize

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

As the title says, I am using the twitter Bootstrap CSS scaffolding system to set up columns using the fluid grid system.  I would like these columns to remain a fixed width on resize of the browser (I have things within these columns that get "smooshed" together when the browser shrinks).  How would I do this?  Here is the basic code that I am using:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row-fluid">
        <div class="span2">
        </div>
        <div class="span4" style="background-color: white;">
        </div>
        <div class="span4" style="background-color: white;">
            <div class="row-fluid">
                <div class="span6">
                </div>
                <div class="span6">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="span2">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: To clarify, you want a fluid container but fixed column widths? If so you may want to try `display: inline-block`

Comment: Just be aware that the bootstrap may have all kinds of styling that may interfere. Floats, fluid container... etc. You may want to avoid the twitter bootstrap for the main layout. Maybe first make a site skeleton first and then integrate the bootstrap styles.

Comment: this didn't solve the issue.  I want the columns to remain the same pixel size as the browser is resized.

Comment: Actually, that's a good use case for inline-block. Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/d497H/2/) I made:  You can try it out. Floats could work too. Here's a [good overview](http://designshack.net/articles/css/whats-the-deal-with-display-inline-block/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you should change the position of the divs, you want to stay fixed, to absolute or fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you want some columns fixed with fluid container? If so you can try this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22471138/1252528

UPDATE:
I think you don't need use bootstrap to layout, just add `display: table` to the container div and `display: table-cell` to the span element which you want to set fixed width can archive that.

Comment: FYI, It can't be answer as it's just a link to an existing SO thread.

Comment: @PareshMayani, yes, maybe this question is duplicated.