# bootstrap3 how to insert div-blocks to the left and the right of container

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

block's width should takes as much space as is left on the screen width on sides.
[image]

Thank you

Comment: You need to make it more clear in your question what happens with the first and third columns at screen widths too small to show them. What's their minimum width?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Bootstrap 3.0 - Fluid Grid that includes Fixed Column Sizes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19231742/bootstrap-3-0-fluid-grid-that-includes-fixed-column-sizes)

Answer (score 0):

what would you do with does blocks on small screens, where the container gets full width? Why don't you do something like this:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class='col-md-2'><!-- Block --></div>
    <div class='col-md-8'><!-- Container --></div>
    <div class='col-md-2'><!-- Block --></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Or if you want the blocks on the side to be hidden on mobile:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class='col-md-2 hidden-sm'><!-- Block --></div>
    <div class='col-md-8 col-sm-12'><!-- Container --></div>
    <div class='col-md-2 hidden-sm'><!-- Block --></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: my container takes max-970px and if screen have more space then user should see these blocks.

Comment: Ideally, I should make page with one block - 970px in the middle and if screen have free space - then add two blocks in the left and right of middle block and fill this space. For design important that middle block take 970px and is in the middle.

Comment: then you'll have to write some custom css, not possible with pure bootstrap I believe