# Bootstrap 3.3.2 fixed width column on large screen but stacks on small screen?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

How to make a column in Bootstrap 3.3.2 to be fixed width on large screen (min-width: 768px) but also stacks on small screen (max-width: 767px)?

Did some research and found [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26849081/49318) works half the puzzle, but how to further make it stacks on small screen like a responsive column is doing?

Thus far I tried:

```
@media (max-width: 767px) {
    .col-fixed-160 {
        width:100%;
    }
    .col-fixed-240 {
        width:100%;
    }
}
```

But it doesn't work.

Comment: could u plz show any image to explain?

Answer (score -1):

you need to use the classes that bootstrap includes, something like

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="col-lg-8 col-md-12">
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-12">
    </div>
</div>
```