# In bootstrap, how to split page into 2 columns, and left part has a fixed width

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am new to bootstrap and css. I want to split whole page into 2 parts, left part looks like a sidebar which has fixed width and doesn't respond to browser window sizing.

Now I am using grid system:

```
.row
   .col-xs-4  //left part
       .row
       .row
       .row
       .row
   .col-xs-8  //right part
       .row
       .row
```

However since grid system is responsive so when I resize browser window, left part's width also changes.

Comment: See question [Bootstrap 3.0 - Fluid Grid that includes Fixed Column Sizes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19231742/bootstrap-3-0-fluid-grid-that-includes-fixed-column-sizes)

Comment: Fixed side can use pixels, responsive side can use %.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest keeping the left menu out of the Bootstrap grid system and using pure CSS to do it.

Comment: Hi, could you give me an example?